# Join values only on a selected number of digits in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to do a join from a column that has values with multiple digits (4 or 5 digits numbers) with another column also with digits (2,3,4,5 digits). The join should only be done on the 5 digit numbers.

```
Input         
Post_full     Post_new
23            11
2345          23           
23456         234          
34567         2345         
              23456        
Output
23456   (As this is the only 5 digit value in the input on both sides)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm) function in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select t1.Post_full
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t1.Post_full = t2.Post_new
where length(t1.Post_full) = 5 and length(t2.Post_new) = 5
```

Comment: You can omit the last `WHERE` condition as it is irrelevant.  -- `and length(t2.Post_new) = 5` . WHERE clause should contain only one condition of length.

Comment: Restricting the number of rows before the join is better for performance.

Comment: but calling `Lenght()` function on all the records of the `table2` will be bad for performance due to Context switching.

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 it's not context switching if it's entirely within SQL; I think you mean "due to the function calls"

Comment: Join a table of 100 rows to another table of 100 rows. There are 10000 combinations to check. If WHERE returns 10 rows for t1 and 10 rows for t2 then there are 100 combinations to check. This is what you gain if you decrease the number of rows before the join.

Comment: All this is theoretical. The optimizer can do better.

Comment: @forpas Thank you that is working perfectly. If I wanted to added a further constraint such as to join on the number of digits on both columns are = 5....or if number of digits on both columns = 2, how would you implement this ?

Comment: Do this: `where length(t1.Post_full) IN (2, 5) and length(t2.Post_new) IN (2, 5) `